# Wrapping AST transformation for Java classes

Tags: java, groovy

I have written an AST transformation, which will wrap the method with `try-catch` block.

The annotation is called `ExceptionHandle`. This is working in groovy, when I add to any of the methods.

But the same annotation added to the Java class, doesnt work.

It is like Java doesnt support AST transformation that is written in groovy?

Comment: Yep. It is only used by the groovy compiler

Answer (score 0):

Groovy AST only works with a groovy compiler. Since Java and Groovy are compiled differently down to Java bytecode, you can't use AST with .java files